# pandas how do I retrieve the index column of multiIndex

Tags: python, pandas

```
t= pd.DataFrame(dict(p1=[1,2,3,4],p2=rand(4),idx=[1]*4)).set_index(['idx','p1'])
```

I can do `it['p2']`
.But doing
`t['p1']`

gives me 
    KeyError: 'p1'

Comment: You made p1 an index, thus it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made `p1` an index, thus you cant access it normally. To get `p1` values, you can do as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import rand

t= pd.DataFrame(dict(p1=[1,2,3,4],p2=rand(4),idx=[1]*4)).set_index(['idx', 'p1'])

print(t.index.get_level_values('p1'))
# or
print(t.index.get_level_values('p1').tolist())
```

Prints:

```
Int64Index([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype='int64')
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```